# Identify this LED strip and suggestions for controllers

Tags: led, led-driver, led-strip, rgb

I am trying to find how to use this LED strip. If you can find anything about this please suggest me some controllers. Please refer to these photos. I found this while cleaning the house. It has two ends but the LEDs have 6 legs. Is it RGB or single colour?

[image: led has 6 legs]

[image: led has only two ends]

Answer (score 3):

The LEDs appear to be multi-chip LEDs which could be single- or multi-colour, common anode, common cathode or independent.

But this doesn't matter since the strip has 2 wires (i.e. no extra control wires) and the cut points have "12V" marking.

So, this could be a single-colour LED strip that runs off 12V supply voltage. Or maybe there's a controller chip (on the other side of the strip) to generate some pre-set lighting effects, but even if there's you can't control it.

What you can try is to find a 12V source (preferably at least 1A, though it's almost impossible to say anything about the current consumption), connect red wire to positive and black one to negative of the supply and see what happens.